# SpringBoot Admin and logging

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I have created a SpringBoot Admin Server where clients register to it. I wish to be able to change logging levels at runtime in the 'Logging' tab in the SpringBoot Admin Server. In one of the clients, my problem is creating a parent logger for all loggers in the package "ke.co.betatech" where I would change the logging level for Logger.getLogger("ke.co.betatech") at runtime and the descendant's logging level changes. I don't want to use the root logger to change the logging level since it changes the logging levels for all loggers registered.

```
package ke.co.betatech.controllers;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class Controller2 implements IController {

  Logger LOG;

  public Controller2() {
     LOG = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
  }

  @GetMapping("/greeting")
  public String hello() {
    LOG.info("Hello");
    return "hello"
  }
}
```

In the main class this is what I attempted

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class LoggingLevelRuntimeApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // I created the parent logger here
      Logger log = Logger.getLogger("ke.co.betatech");
      SpringApplication.run(LoggingLevelRuntimeApplication.class, args);
   }
}
```

The problem is, the logger `Logger.getLogger("ke.co.betatech")` does not appear in the list of loggers in the Spring Boot Admin Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show the package loggers if you click on the symbol right next to the search input on the logging page.

[image]

Comment: That worked. Though I noticed something; using your image above as an example, if `com.netflix` is set at a lower logging level, `com` no longer has "control" over `com.netflix`. To clarify, if `com` is at `INFO` then `com.netflix` will also be at `INFO`. If we set `com.netflix` to `DEBUG`, `com` no longer limits `com.netflix` to its logging level.

Comment: yeah that's how things work in logback. The only thing what's missing in the ui is to switch back the configuredLevel to `null` so that parent loggers can influence the effectiveLevel again.

Answer (score 0):

Add `logging.level.ke.co.betatech=DEBUG` in your `application.properties` file and you will be able to use the logger using
`Logger log = Logger.getLogger("ke.co.betatech");` in any class once after `SpringApplication.run()` completes.

Comment: I have done as suggested and all descendants of `Logger.getLogger("ke.co.betatech")` are set on level `DEBUG` on start up. But my problem is: 

1. to be able to do this at runtime using SpringBoot Admin Server. 
2. `Logger.getLogger("ke.co.betatech")` is not available in the list of loggers in SpringBoot Admin Server